# Firefox 3.6.28 assets load from cache slower than from server

Tags: performance, firefox, caching

I find that my web page's js/css file load from browser cache in Firefox 3.6.28 is so slow.

The time spent in loading directly from server is much smaller.

Here is the Firebug net panel show that the time spend in loading from server:

[image]

Here is the time spend in loading from cache(the grey color means it was taken from cache):

[image]

I know Firefox 3.6.28 is so old and the newest version of Firefox don't have such a problem.

But why the old version of Firefox load a 1kb js from cache can cause 500+ms?

My Firefox's disk and memory cache is turning on.

My PC environment is:

CPU:Intel atom 230 1.6G
RAM:1G

Can anyone give me some explanation？

Thx.

Comment: Doesn't look like anythings is taken from cache, in that case response should be `304 Not Modified`. Have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526632/why-does-firefox-3-6-8-not-cache-static-contents-from-asp-net-developer-server?rq=1

Comment: @Pavlo I did doubt that was not take from cache,but it's an old version Firebug and I found out that when it was grey(not the black),it did load from cache.When I used HTTPWatch,it show that the js was load from cache.

Comment: That version of Firefox is unsupported (End-of-Life) anyway. It is really impossible to tell you why your cache is slow, but my guess would be that the cache location is slow (networked drive, disk fragmentation, slow/pre-failing disk, disk space) or your your available physical memory is low so that the in-memory cache gets (repeatedly) swapped to a (slow) disk.

Comment: @nmaier Thx.I agreed with your guess.However, I disabled memory cache or disk memory and can't find anything special happened.My physical memory is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally，I figure out why so slow.

Firstly,just as what @nmaier said,it's an old version of Firefox,so its speed is slow.Even in my PC(i3/4G RAM) this version of Firefox spends 100~200ms to read from cache.

But the 500+ms is happened in a poor performance machine(CPU:Intel atom 230 1.6G RAM:1G,it's a special PC placed in the building waiting for customer,so its performance is poor).

However,our system is based on heavy ajax to load div contents,and that when a ajax get html from server,the html may contains js script ,then, the browser is rebuilding the DOM and redisplay the page and it is reading file from the cache in the same time.This is a very huge work to Firefox 3.6.

So the time is so slow.