# Why ASP.NET pages render faster on IE than Chrome or FF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis

Why does ASP.NET pages render time on Chrome and FF is ~ 3X the render time on IE ??
This problem only persist on my local machine, but when published to the real server the complete opposite happens (expected, as FF and Chrome outperform IE).

I tried Windows 7 x64 and Windows XP x86 with FF 3.6, Chrome 9, and IE 8.

Is there any thing I can do on IIS or in the web config to fix this behavior ?

**EDIT**: In response to the responses an domments:

1. I ***don't*** have these issues when running PHP + apache, or JSP
2. I noticed this behavior when doing a debugging session in VS or after deploying on IIS
3. Modifying the hosts file **did** improve Chrome and FF response time indeed, but still slower than IE !

Comment: Are you talking about a debugging session from Visual Studio or similar, or surfing to a localhost .aspx page ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve the problem, try loading 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. You can also explicitly map localhost to 127.0.0.1 in your host file.
It's located on the following location:

> %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Then you need to add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Comment: @FearUs - this issue is 'discussed' in more detail on this SO thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726585/firefox-and-chrome-slow-on-localhost-known-fix-doesnt-work-on-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

For firefox when testing on a localhost with cassini web server you should turn off IPV6 this will speed it up a lot:

In the Location bar, type about:config and press Enter.
The about:config "This might void your warranty!" warning page may appear. Click I'll be careful, I promise!, to continue to the about:config page.
In the Filter field, type network.dns.disableIPv6.
In the list of preferences, double-click network.dns.disableIPv6 to set its value to true.