# Firefox slow on localhost

Tags: performance, firefox, localhost

File load times for Firefox 9.0.1 are about 6 seconds (page has some php code) but IE is instant. If I change the link from localhost to 127.0.0.1 Firefox will load instantly as well.

I've made the changes recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726585/firefox-and-chrome-slow-on-localhost-known-fix-doesnt-work-on-windows-7)

I've uncommented out the following line in my C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

But no luck.I've tried seting network.dns.disableIPv6 to true with no luck.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I closed down Dreamweaver and lo and behold the changes took effect. Possibly Dreamweaver was interfering. Anyway, things are instant now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with you browser's DNS settings.

Try using this DNS service (it's free)

https://store.opendns.com/setup/

Also clear your DNS cache in firefox:

> Mozilla Firefox (Win & Mac)
>   Go to the Tools menu, select Clear Recent History and check all boxes. Under Time range to >clear select Everything (except passwords, if desired) and click Clear Now.

And maybe also on your windows:

> Run->cmd and type in: ipconfig /flushdns

Comment: If you're looking for quick and easy to remember DNS, Google's are at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. No setup required

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox 94:
Including answers mentioned above: When using Firefox in private mode, **try disabling private mode**.

Set "Always create chronic" (1st Option) in Settings > Privacy & Security > Chronic.