# MVC 5 reload extremely slow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I've tried every solution on **StackOverflow** so far and I can't get it to get an acceptable performance.

I'm in the developing process (not even close to publish), each time I change a single character on a `.cshtml` file and reload the browser, it takes **half a minute or more** to reload.

What is wrong? I haven't tweaked any setting other than **Edit and Continue** under Web/debugger property (because that was one answer in **StackOverflow**) after the project was generated from scratch.

**EDIT 1:**

The controller method is defined as the following:

```
public ActionResult Create() { return View(); }
```

The page took `2 minutes` in loading as per **Google Chrome** network statistics (in localhost) with a size of **6KB**, and it happened after I modified the css `classname` for 3 `<input>` tags

Comment: Are you using full IIS or IIS Express? Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: IIS Express with Chrome

Comment: it might be due to several reasons. it is very hard to tell. You have to show some code. How s your database calls etc?

Comment: I'm currently working on the `Create.cshmtl` which doesn't have a database call. The controller literally just calls the view and that's it.

Comment: I'm assuming the slowness is experienced only on the firs refresh after updating the source? Any subsequent refreshes work as expected?

Comment: Yes. First time after updating the view, it is slow (sometimes takes 3 seconds, some other takes 30-60+ seconds).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? This describes my situation exactly... many hours trying to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

try to disable "browser link" feature. You can find that option in dropdown menu of reload icon (the one between start debug and solution configuration dropdown).

Let me know if you notice any change.

Have a nice day,

Alberto

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, unfortunately I have already tried that :(

Comment: ok, can you provide us with more details on your code? the problem is the TTFB or action execution itself?

Comment: Probably the TTFB, since according to Chrome, html page took 2 minutes in loading (6 KB), after I changed the css class to 3 inputs

Answer (score 0):

It might just be the compile time if you're only experiencing the slowness the first time you refresh after the update. Try clearing the cache after the first refresh in the browser to see if reloads are faster than the first one. You'd know for sure if you have more pages and browse between them.

Try disabling the IPv6 in your browser. Also, take a look at this for additional tweaks:

[Firefox and Chrome slow on localhost; known fix doesn't work on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726585/firefox-and-chrome-slow-on-localhost-known-fix-doesnt-work-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in VS 2022. Solved with:
Options > Projects and Solutions > ASP.NET Core > CSS Hot Reload: > change to **Disabled**